MS Lists Validation Setting - how to create a formula
I am using =[FAY Date<=[Clearance Date] and is working but I do not know how to include [FAY Date<=[Contract End].
How do I combine both into one formula to use in MS List Validation Setting. Also, there is not always a Contract End date for personnel classed as permanent and that would need to be ignored.
Any assistance will be very much appreciated.

I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you?

If you want to combine both conditions using AND logical operator, try using list validation formula in below format:
=AND([FAY Date]<=[Clearance Date],IF(ISBLANK([Contract End]),TRUE,[FAY Date]<=[Contract End]))

Follow my answers given in below threads to add formula in List validation settings:

List validation to make multiple fields mandatory if dropdown meets condition
How to have validation for calculated column

Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].

